# Reative and absolute convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For which p series $S=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \log^2{(\sqrt[n]{n})}\frac{\cos{(\frac{n^2 \pi}{n+1})}} {(1+n)^p\log^3{n}}$ converges and absolutely converges?

Convergence: $S=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\log^2{n}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cos{(\frac{\pi}{n+1})}} {(1+n)^p\log^3{n}}=\sum_{n=2}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cos{\frac{\pi}{n+1}}}{n^2(n+1)^p\log{n}}$. This series converges for $p>-2$ by Abel's test?
Absolute convergence: $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\cos{\frac{\pi}{n+1}}}{n^2(n+1)^p\log{n}}$. When does this series converges?
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you replace the `cos` with the two first terms of its Taylor expansion?

Comment: @Ripi2 $\cos{\frac{\pi}{n+1}}=1+\frac{\pi^2}{(n+1^2)}$ when $n\to\infty$ but I still cannot conclude the convergence.